# Displaying a legend for a centroid, simple marker with size overwrite?

Tags: qgis, legend, centroids

I am new to QGIS and can't figure out how to display a legend for the dot size of a centroid, simple marker. The size of the dot is dependent on a value from a CSV linked to a layer map of Europe. I have two dots per country (different years). This is a snippet of the map:

[image]

Now what I need is to be able to display a legend for the size of the dots. It is showing me a legend in the "symbol size" menu:
[image]

I was able to create a legend while using graduated symbols. I also tried using graduated and then switch method to "size". However, even in a new project, the only option I get is color:

[image]

So this is not an option either. I'm using QGIS 3.8.

Edit: Conerning Josephs answer: I can't find this optione. I do have the advanced dropdown on certain levels, but not on all of them. Here with Screenshots:
First level:
[image]
Second level:
[image]
Third level:
[image]
Fourth level:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you may try using a QGIS plugin [Proportional circles](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProportionalCircles/).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have defined the field for your `Size` parameter, there is an *advanced* option where you could set the **data-defined size legend** if you click on the top main marker. Here you can set the size legend manually or use the values automatically from the field you specified:

[image: Data-defined size legend]

Comment: Hey Jospeh, Thanks for your help! However, I can't find this option. I did edit the first post and add some screenshots. It also seems that I have three levels for the marker and you only two (Marker -> Simple marker). For me it is centroid Fill -> Marker -> Simple Marker. Might this be the reason why I can't find the option? Thanks & best, Stefan

Comment: @Stefan - Apologies, when you mentioned using a csv I assumed you were using a point shapefile which is where this option is available. I don't think it's possible using it for a line/polygon shapefile. An alternative could be to create a new point layer which uses data from the csv or polygon layer and then add the size legend.

Comment: Hey Jospeh, no need to apologize - you're trying to help :) I figured that ou myself by now. My idea was using the vector polygons tools -> Polygon centroids. This way I get a point layer. The only problem: with the linked csv I was able to uncheck "Draw point on part of every multi-part features". I can't do that now and this means that there X points per country. Any input here? I also can't filter the attibute tables becaus it does not include any coordinates.

Comment: @Stefan - You could run the **Dissolve** tool and select the country field. This merges all features which have the same country value.